# Advanced editing features of Emacs

Tags: emacs

there's a *lot* of noise about super awesome features of Emacs. Be it [org-mode](http://orgmode.org/), [Gnus](http://gnus.org/) or [C-x M-c butterfly](http://xkcd.com/378/). I've used Emacs for years, so no need to convince me.

What I personally found is that nobody talks about...actually **editing** text. You know that

> Emacs is a nice OS but it lacks an decent editor.

joke? I didn't really get it until I grokked Vim.

Now, I wrote my thesis using Emacs as my text editor, so my heart is somehow still attached to it. I'm also super envious about org-mode. So I wondered whether there maybe actually *are* features I've been missing all the time?

I'm going to give you a few examples I use all the time:

- `o`/`O` opens a new line above/below the current and puts me into insert mode no matter at which position my cursor is.
- `ci'` deletes the contents of current/following '-string and puts me into insert mode.
- `dat` deletes the current HTML tag. `cit` would delete the contents and put me into insert mode. `cstt` would let me edit the tag (eg make a `<span>` into a `<div>`)
- `cs([` changes the surrounding "(" and ")" into "[" and "]".
- An extension allows me to address Python indentations: `dai` would delete the current indented block, `\\ai` would comment it out (\\ is an extension).

Are there some super secret shortcuts but easily accessible shortcuts for stuff like this in Emacs? [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2) has a few "expand selection" functions that go a similar way albeit not that precise--but still it's very useful.

P.S. Please don't bring up any vi emulation, just don't.

P.P.S. Also for god's sake, no Emacs vs. Vim vs. Whatever warfare, I beg you.

Comment: Your question highlights exactly why the emacs vs vim religious war exists.  There are many features in my muscle memory that I would lose if I went from my loved emacs to vim and I in no way miss the features you list (to my knowledge you listed features are not part of emacs, although there may be extensions that add them).  My advice is to stay with vim.

Comment: Try [the emacs help list](http://news.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.help). There are lots of seasoned emacs experts there who may know some clever editing tricks.

Comment: I read "I wrote my thesis on Emacs" as "I wrote my thesis about Emacs". I was very intrigued at first.

Comment: This is an old post, but I found perusing the binds is pretty cool. C-h b will get you to the buffer for that. I yanked all of that into scratch and cut off all the fat. Found some cool stuff in there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Look for this wiki page.](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsNiftyTricks) It have a lot and lot of tricks. Most of them I found(suddenly) for myself before reading, but this article worth reading.

Try `C-h k` every `C-<key> M-<key>`. Something like `M-c, M-l, M-u` proves useful for me, `M-z` for `zap-to-char`. Platinum answer would be "learn to use i-search". `C-w, C-M-y, M-r` are super-useful while in i-search mode.

I don't know *any* packages, which helps me for editing something, that surround my point. One day I wrote one for myself, but it proved useless. If I will mind write something again, first thing I'll do - think, what should I write. What about their behavior? Shold it be N separate commands for every type of brackets, or one, but smart? How should it work? Kill for keyring use? (Discussions are welcome).

For ~lisp, I use sexp editing commands.

There is something I wrote for myself.

```
(defun cm-fast-step-upward ()
  "Step 3 lines up, recenteres the screen."
  (interactive)
  (forward-line -3)
  (recenter))

(defun cm-fast-step-downward ()
  "Step 3 lines down, recenteres the screen."
  (interactive)
  (forward-line 3)
  (recenter))

(defun cm-find-any-bracket-forward()
  "Search for \"_}_]_'_>_)_end forward"
  (interactive)
  (re-search-forward "[\"}'>)]\\|\\(end\\)\\|\\]"))

(defun cm-find-any-bracket-backward()
  "Search for \"_{_[_'_<_(_begin forward"
  (interactive)
  (re-search-backward "[\"{'<(]\\|\\(begin\\)\\|\\["))

(defun cm-find-nonspace-backward()
  "Search for non tab, space, newline symbol backward."
  (interactive)
  (if (and
        (search-backward-regexp "[ 
  ]" (point-min) t)
        (search-backward-regexp "[^ 
  ]" (point-min) t))
    (forward-char)
    (goto-char (point-min))))

(defun cm-find-nonspace-forward()
  "Search for non tab, space, newline symbol backward."
  (interactive)
  (if (and
        (search-forward-regexp "[ 
  ]" (point-max) t)
        (search-forward-regexp "[^ 
  ]" (point-max) t))
  (backward-char)
  (goto-char (point-max))))

(defun cm-backward-delete-word(&optional arg)
  "DELETE word before cursor. Warning, this word cannot be yanked."
  (interactive "p")
  (let ((beg (point)))
    (backward-word arg)
    (delete-region beg (point))) )

(defun cm-delete-word(&optional arg)
  "DELETE word after cursor. Warning, this word cannot be yanked."
  (interactive "p")
  (let ((beg (point)))
    (forward-word arg)
    (delete-region beg (point))) )

(defun cm-delete-line(&optional arg)
  "DELETE line after cursor. Warning, this line cannot be yanked."
  (interactive "P")
  (if (equal arg '-) (setq arg -1))
  (let ((beg (point)))
    (if arg (forward-line arg)
    (goto-char (point-at-eol)))
    (if (= beg (point))
      (delete-char 1 nil)
      (delete-region beg (point)))))

(defun cm-reverse-region (&optional arg)
  "Reverse current region, like this: \"a(bc) d\" -> \"d )cb(a\"."
  (interactive "P")
  (let ((reversed (apply 'string (reverse (string-to-list (buffer-substring-no-properties (region-beginning) (region-end)))))))
    (delete-region (region-beginning) (region-end))
    (insert reversed)))

(provide 'cmmove)
```

I never shared(should I?) this thing before, you are welcome to leave comments.

Default bindings use hyper-key

```
(global-set-key [?\H-f] 'cm-find-nonspace-forward)
(global-set-key [?\H-b] 'cm-find-nonspace-backward)
(global-set-key [?\H-\]] 'cm-find-any-bracket-forward)
(global-set-key [?\H-\[] 'cm-find-any-bracket-backward)
(global-set-key [?\H-p] 'cm-fast-step-upward)
(global-set-key [?\H-n] 'cm-fast-step-downward)
(global-set-key (kbd "H-t") 'cm-reverse-region)
```

I wish also to find out, which behavior do you like for this commands. If they fail to find something, should they message or throw error?

Comment: First of: Thanks for not being defensive and arguing that you don't need features for actually editing text in Emacs. :) I'll have a look at your code tomorrow (it's evening where I live ;)). The wiki page already had some cool stuff like tinyeat. Functions like "delete inner string" would be handy and easy to implement.

Comment: BTW, https://github.com/rejeep/wrap-region seems to do some magic with surrounding characters, so take care you don't do duplicate work.

Comment: That's not so hard to wrap given region(but thanks for link, that might be useful). The key thing I am thinking about now, is how to properly find things around point. `find-any-bracket-forward` is simple and good, but how about searching forward for "bracket" in your level, example: ``"[] <pointer> (()) "" () "`` and you should find last char if searching forward, and first, if backward. Things looks even more complicated when you think about those damn ``"`` brackets, where left and right bracket are equal.

Answer (score 13):

Since no one has said so directly, I will.

The reason emacs lacks a "decent editor" is because a large part of the *point* of emacs is to  allow you to make the **ideal** editor for yourself. This is not a trivial undertaking, and there are many things that other people have written and enough people have found useful to be included in the standard distributions of it.

It's not meant to be used at the default settings, really. Really. It's not meant to be a piece of software that you poke and prod at and tweak a bit here and there so much as an editor that you can tear apart the behavior of to make into whatever you want it to be.

So, yes, yes there is either an existing equivalent of `$feature` from `$editor`, or assuming no one has written one yet you can be safe in the knowledge that you can implement it.

Comment: Given the answers and my own experiences, I have to agree on that. It's a pity though that you have to program a decent editor when coming to Emacs. The single biggest reason why there isn't much by default or more concentrated efforts seems to be lack of interest though. The net is full of "how to make Emacs cook your coffee" and how to avoid rsi but lacks editing howtos and guides.

Comment: The bad side is that this editing info is very hard to find. Users implement something, but where can I read their implementations(inb4 dotemacs: there lot of non-editing stuff there)? I think most of them are in their own `.emacs` or `.emacs.d/<whatever>`. Why not to make some place about editing features? I think this question is good place to post something.

Comment: "It's not meant to be used at the default settings, really. Really."  Does the GNU Emacs Manual mention this?

Comment: @RaffaeleRicciardi not explicitly, but it's been mentioned multiple times on the `emacs-help` ML, and the Emacs and Elisp manuals both place a heavy emphasis on telling you how you can (safely) change behavior. Emacs is meant to provide you the *means* to have an ideal development setup, as that tends to be something that varies wildly from individual to individual, at least among the type of people who tend to use and love Emacs.

Answer (score 7):

There is no answer to your question.

It is a continuous journey, one that you can begin by typing <kbd>M-x help</kbd>, and doing this frequently.

Everyone has a different set of features they can't live without.  So, other than just listing all the text editing features available, try (re-)reading the [tour of Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/tour/), the [FAQ](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/emacs-faq.html), and the [Emacs manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/index.html).  The most active places to find plugin information is the [Emacs Wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/) and the [Emacs Lisp Package Archive](http://tromey.com/elpa/) (to be distributed with Emacs 24).

99% of the features you don't know about will be found in the above links.

Of course, you can also look at the standard SO question/answer: [what is the single most useful feature...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60367/the-single-most-useful-emacs-feature).

Comment: There are zero editing related answers on the first page of the SO question/answer. I have been looking through these lists and posts and nothing focused on actual working with text. :(

Comment: @hynek I see (in order) auto completion of words, align-regexp, keyboard macros, rectangle commands, yasnippet, delete-blank-lines, transpose-*, comment-region (uncomment).  All of which are directly related to inserting/deleting/modifying text.  They may not be what you're looking for, but that's kind of the point of my answer.

Comment: I'm kind of hoping for vim -> Emacs converts to chip in, that have enough experience to compare. I found the stuff too "high level". The reason for my question more or less stems from the existence of ST2 which has fair editing capabilities (just as an example: there's a key command for expanding intelligently the selection scope to parens, quotes, tags etc) w/o having a command mode. I hoped there are some hidden gems for Emacs too. Because you know, ST2 has no org-mode. :)

Comment: @hynek Fair enough.  I'd suggest, then, a possibly more fruitful way to get the kind of information you're looking for by asking more specific questions about tasks you do, e.g. "how do I do X when editing HTML?" It's more laborious, but I guess us Emacs-weenies don't often focus on the text editing features (which is what your question goes to).

Comment: @hynek, I think you're looking in the wrong place. For basic editing commands, of which there are a boat-load, the place to go is the fine manual (`C-h r` from inside Emacs). There aren't a lot of questions about this on SO, or third-party guides on the web, because the docs that ship with Emacs are complete and well-written. SO is where people come when they *can't* find the answer in the manual, so the low-level stuff gets filtered out.

Answer (score 5):

- The vim `o/O` command is a two key command in emacs. For `o`, `C-e <return>` (end of line, return to create new line).  For `O`, `C-a C-o` (beginning of line, open line).
- `ffap-copy-string-as-kill` (not bound to a key by default, but easily fixed) does something similar to your `ci'`.  In emacs, there is no concept of "insert mode".

I don't change "(" ")" to "[" "]" enough to learn a key sequence for it.  If I had to do it I would turn to `query-replace-regexp` (`C-M-%`) first.

I don't edit python or HTML much, but I'm sure there are clever tricks in appropriate modes for your needs.

Edited in response to comments.

More advanced editing features that I use frequently:

- Keyboard macros.  This is a broad category of tricks, but if there are many similar edits that I have to make throughout a buffer, I record a macro and repeat it.  If the macro is very useful, it can be saved for future sessions.  This can be very powerful when seek is part of the macro.  An example of usage is taking a definition of an `enum` in C and creating a switch statement out of it quickly.  See http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/KeyboardMacros and http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/KeyboardMacrosTricks for details.
- Whenever I use vim, I alway miss incremental search.  Not advanced, but I find it much easier to use than search in vim, particularly when I'm not sure of the spelling of what I'm trying to find.
- Marks.  Every time you start an incremental search, the current position is pushed to the mark stack so that it is fast to return to your previous position.  You can push a mark at anytime and pop the mark stack to go back through interesting points in the buffer.  See http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MarkCommands.
- TRAMP mode for editing files on remote machines.  See http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TrampMode.
- Rectangle edits.  `string-insert-rectangle` and `rectangle-delete` are good friends of mine.

It is hard to know what you will find useful.  Every user will have a different favorite feature.  The feature that made me start using emacs was `M-x compile`.  Use `M-g n` to jump to the file location of the next error or warning in the compilation output.

Comment: I know there is no insert mode, as said I used Emacs for several years. :) Back then I didn't miss advanced editing functions as well, until I saw vim and Sublime Text (which is modeless). C-o seems to insert a newline without moving on. What I mean is exactly the opposite: go up or down, add a line and don't break the current one. It's unfortunate that everybody is clinging to my examples, I just tried to show a variety of what's possible. All I'm asking are editing features Emacs power users couldn't live without and I might have missed. I don't see how such questions highlight anything.

Comment: Maybe people can't give you good answers, because for others editing tricks are not the most important way to be more productive with Emacs. For example, in my case having packages like [Anything](http://metasandwich.com/2010/07/30/what-can-i-get-for-10-dolla-anything-el/) add much more to my productivity than having a key for changing parens and stuff would.

Comment: Given Emacs' power, it shouldn't be a question of "Anything XOR effective editing". There has been already a good answer here and maybe we can start off something to make Emacs a better _editor_.

Comment: Regarding your edit: vim has incsearch, just put a `set incsearch` into your .vimrc (or type `:set incsearch`). Thanks for adding the stuff you did! (the C-o point is still wrong though, I'd remove it to avoid misleading people)

Answer (score 4):

I'm not an Emacs expert, but https://sites.google.com/site/steveyegge2/effective-emacs seems to cover some useful examples. Especially items 6 (buffer control) and 7 (lose the UI) seem worth memorizing. Also, the comment section covers some readers' tips.

Comment: I know that article and except for Item 3 it's exactly missing what I'm asking: Efficient editing of text. :) `backward-kill-word` can't be the only editing hack. :-/

Comment: One day I found [this](http://ruslanspivak.com/2010/09/22/c-w-to-delete-word-backward-in-conkeror/) when I was browsing for conkeror stuff. I think it's better than Item3 solution.

Comment: Oh, and one thing: I rewrote it just now, because that code from my link cannot kill region when there is no mark, and I use it frequently. Adding `C-u C-x C-x` for every kill-region is not good. [I think using ARG is good workaround.](http://www.everfall.com/paste/id.php?8jmxo12l0zf5)

Answer (score 2):

You may have a look at

```
thing-at-point-utils.el
```

It provides stuff like that:

- `ar-brace-or-copy-atpt`

  "If region is highlighted, provide THING at point with brace(s),
  otherwise copy brace(ed) at point.
  With NO-DELIMITERS, copy brace(ed) without delimiters. 
  With negative argument kill brace(ed) at point. "
- `ar-bracket-or-copy-atpt`

  "If region is highlighted, provide THING at point with bracket(s),
  otherwise copy bracket(ed) at point.
  With NO-DELIMITERS, copy bracket(ed) without delimiters. 
  With negative argument kill bracket(ed) at point. "
- `ar-lesser-angle-or-copy-atpt`

  "If region is highlighted, provide THING at point with lesser-angle(s),
  otherwise copy lesser-angle(ed) at point.
  With NO-DELIMITERS, copy lesser-angle(ed) without delimiters. 
  With negative argument kill lesser-angle(ed) at point. "

Keys in use here:

```
(global-set-key [(control c)(<)] 'ar-lesser-angle-or-copy-atpt)
(global-set-key [(control c)(>)] 'ar-greater-angle-or-copy-atpt)
(global-set-key [(control c)(\")] 'ar-doublequote-or-copy-atpt)
(global-set-key [(control c)(\')] 'ar-singlequote-or-copy-atpt)
(global-set-key [(control c)(\))] 'ar-parentize-or-copy-atpt)
(global-set-key [(control c)(\\)] 'ar-backslash-or-copy-atpt)
(global-set-key [(control c)(\])] 'ar-bracket-or-copy-atpt)
(global-set-key [(control c)(\})] 'ar-brace-or-copy-atpt)
(global-set-key [(control c)(_)] 'ar-underscore-or-copy-atpt)
(global-set-key [(control c)(super \})] 'ar-brace-or-copy-atpt)
(global-set-key [(control c)(\/)] 'ar-slash-or-copy-atpt)
```

Source:

```
https://launchpad.net/s-x-emacs-werkstatt
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you said don't mention any vi emulation modes, but if you haven't you should really give [Evil](http://gitorious.org/evil/pages/Home) a look since it really does give you basically the fully power of vi's text manipulation inside Emacs. The best of both worlds really - Emacs awesome extensibility with vi's powerful text manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

OK, this probably isn't super secret, but I use it constantly.

Its the occur command
<Show all lines in the current buffer containing a match for REGular EXPression>

For example, it's very useful for showing all the lines where a particular variable is used.

M-x occur <Enter> <type in your search target> then <Enter>
This'll open up a new buffer showing the matched lines.
You can move the cursor to each occurrence using the command:
next-error

For me, they aren't convenient at all unless you re-define keys to run the commands.
So, I map control-o to the occur command, and control-n to the next-error command.

To do that (or your own key(s))
put this in your .emacs file:
(global-set-key "\C-o" 'occur)
(global-set-key "\C-n" 'next-error)

Comment: Note that C-n globally is a bad key; though I don't use them myself to navigate, c-p, c-n, c-f, c-b it is terrible advice to suggest to rebind.